# python: TypeError: 'long' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I get this error when trying to convert possible integer variables:

```
for page in domain.page_set.all():
    filename = str(domain.url) + '_page_' +str(page.id())+ '.html'
```

The error:

```
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.4.7-0/apps/django/django_projects/controls/polls/models.py", line 40, in make_config_file
    filename = str(domain.url)+"_page_"+str(page.id())+".html"
TypeError: 'long' object is not callable
```

What is wrong here? what does "long is not callable" means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page.id` is a [`long`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/long.html), which is not a function, and thus not callable:

```
In [1]: id = 5586L
In [2]: type(id)
Out[2]: long
In [3]: id()
TypeError: 'long' object is not callable
```

Try just doing `str(page.id)`.

Alternatively, you could use Python's string formatting like so:

```
for page in domain.page_set.all():
    filename = "{}_page_{}.html".format(domain.url, page.id)
```